# stop a tshark command when it finds the right packet

Tags: linux, pcap, tshark

I have a Pcap file with a rather big size. I just want to read one packet in this file, for example, the 10th packet.

I have a tshark command like this:

```
tshark -r myfile.pcap frame.number == 10 -V
```

The command will continue searching the entire file even when it finds the 10th packet. That takes a long time.

I prefer to stop the command when it finds the packet, how can i do that?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

editcap (part of the wireshark package) can be used to extract one or more specific frames from a pcap file to a new pcap file.

You can then run tshark on the new file. 
(This is a two-step process but for large pcap files it will take less time than tshark will take to read the whole file).

```
Usage: editcap [options] ... <infile> <outfile> [ <packet#>[-<packet#>] ... ]

Packet selection:
  -r                     keep the selected packets; default is to delete them.
```

See `editcap -h` for the complete list of `editcap` options.